# How important is a datasource to quartz-java? Can I use NoSql database as a datasource for quartz?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, quartz-scheduler

I have an java application which uses **dynamoDb** as a database. I need to add a **cronjob** for that service. I am thinking of using **quartz**.

Can I have other datasource for quartz other than relational DB? Or can I use dynamoDb as a datasource for quartz? I have read somewhere that quartz uses the in-memory store if the datasource is not defined, Am I correct?

What are the disadvantages of not using a datasource or using an in-memory datastore?

Comment: If in memory if you restart everything is gone.

Comment: The RamStore(in memory) for quartz does not support clustering of quartz instances.